# Drools KieBuilder with custom class loader not working with ProjectClassLoader

Tags: classloader, drools

I am using drools 6.4.0 Final. I compile java classes on-the-fly using drools NativeJavacompiler so i set the class loader using ProjectClassLoader. Once i compiled all the classes, i stored the ProjectClassLoader as a class loader in my class. Now i have .drl files as well that refers to my external java classes so i set the custom class loader as my ProjectClassLoader which has store map with my compiled classes but the drools build fails with ClassNotFoundException.

KieHelper helper = new KieHelper();
helper.setClassLoader(getMyProjectClassLoader());

If i set URLClassLoader with reference to my physical class files as class loader, it works. Why only URLClassLoader is working and not my drools ProjectClassLoader? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in Advance!